# 作成途中のHTMLでJSONデータ所得作成を完成させたいです。

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

失礼します。いつもお世話になっております。

HTMLでJSONデータ所得を作成途中なのですがあと一歩のところで躓いております。

上記のHTMLでsubmitすると 
「curl -i -v -H "Accept: application/vnd.glv.v1+json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X GET localhost:8280/api/test_accesses -d '{"dept_ids":["000002"]}'」

というリクエストが送られ望んだデータも返却されます。上記のHTMLに 
「~ '{"dept_ids":["000002"],**"start_date":"20151001","end_date":"20151207"}'**」

とリクエストを送るようにしたいのですがどの部分を修正すればいいかわからず、ご存知の方に教えていただきたいと思いました。
追記する"start_date":"20151001","end_date":"20151207"}'の日付部分はテキストボックスを作成して好きな年月を入れられるようにと考えております。

```js
$(function(){
        $("#response").html("Response Values");

        $("#button").click( function(){
            var url = $("#url_post").val();
            var dept_ids = [$("#dept_ids").val()];
      
            var JSONdata = {};
            JSONdata.dept_ids = dept_ids;

            $.ajax({
              url : url
            , type : "POST"
            , data : JSON.stringify(JSONdata)
            , contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            , processData: false
            , dataType : "json"
            , accepts : {json: "application/vnd.glv.v1+json;charset=UTF-8"}
            , crossDomain: false
            }).done(function(data, status, xhr) {
                // 通信成功時の処理
//                alert("成功");
                $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(data));
            }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                // 通信失敗時の処理
                alert("失敗");
            }).always(function(arg1, status, arg2) {
                // 通信完了時の処理
//                alert("完了");
            });
        })
    })
```

```html
<h1>HTMLファイルからPOSTでJSONデータを送信</h1>
    <p>URL: <input type="text" id="url_post" name="url" size="100" value="http://52.192.178.185:8280/api/test_accesses"></p>
    <p>value1: <input type="text" id="dept_ids" size="30" value="000002"></p>
    <p><button id="button" type="button">submit</button></p>
    <textarea id="response" cols=120 rows=10 disabled></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<p>value1: <input type="text" id="dept_ids" size="30" value="000002"></p>`にならって書けば問題ないかと思いましたが、JavaScript内で、`var dept_ids = [$("#dept_ids").val()];`と、テキストボックスから値を取得されていましたので、これにならって書くとすると。

```
<input type="text" id="dept_ids" size="30" value="000002">
<input type="text" id="start_date" size="30" value="">
<input type="text" id="end_date" size="30" value="">
```

と入力項目を用意し、JavaScriptにて、

```
var start_date = $("#start_date").val();
var end_date = $("#end_date").val();
```

とした次のところでJSONデータを作っていますので、

```
var JSONdata = {};
JSONdata.dept_ids = dept_ids;
JSONdata.start_date = start_date;
JSONdata.end_date = end_date;
```

とすれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 直りました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: @たかぽん 質問が解決したときは、回答（複数あればどれか一つ）の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックして、解決済みマークをつけていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: unarist様
解決マークがないと思っていましたがあったんですね・・・
こちらのミスなのにご丁寧にありがとうございます。